# Howto: output a classLibrary-projec to two different places?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, project

Is there any way to let a project output its Dll to two different paths?

Comment: http://dotnetperls.com/post-pre-build-macros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't but you could use a Post Build step to copy the generated assembly to another folder:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you support, CommandText: *copy "{path1}DLLName.dll" "{path2}DLLName.dll"*

Comment: copy "bin\SharePointReportReader.dll" "K:\Development\Projects\Portal 2008\Website\bin\SharePointReportReader.dll"
" exited with code 1.. any help?

Comment: @Remon, look at the Console Output Window (CTRL+W+O)